# Nicedit Pasting Formatting In Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-editor, paste, nicedit

I've just finished implementing [Nicedit](http://www.nicedit.com/) into my website, and I've noticed something particularly annoying with the editor (surprise!). Whenever I copy text from a webpage and paste it into Nicedit, even from my own site, Nicedit will "remember" all of the formatting that the copied text had.

My website is more-or-less forum-based in nature with all odd posts having one background color and all even posts having another. This means that there is a chance that users will try and copy other user's posts and the background of their text will be different from their own post.

The interesting part is that this only happens when I'm using Chrome, not Firefox, or IE. This makes me think the problem has to do with how Chrome copies text from webpages, but I could be wrong.

Anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Someone else had this problem.

Follow the steps at http://billyflaherty.com/blog/2009/a-customized-web-based-wysiwyg-that-can-clean-a-paste-from-ms-word/

Comment: Fantastic link, that's just what I was looking for.